# Is it possible to change the tab order when when using a bot and static tabs in a Teams app?

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

In a Microsoft Teams app we developed using TeamsFX/Teams Toolkit, we have two static tabs and a bot. When we added the bot, it inserted its tab as the first tab in the app. Is it possible to reorder the app's tabs when using a both and static tabs? The customer wants the "Home" page to be the landing page when loading the app. They would also like the bot's tab to be labelled "Bot" instead of "Chat" if possible.

["Chat" tab should be positioned after the "My Nudges" tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWWdf.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with manifest version 1.7, developers can rearrange all tabs in their personal app. In particular, a developer can move the bot chat tab, which always defaults to the first position, anywhere in the personal app tab header. Two reserved tab entityId keywords are declared, conversations and about.

If you create a bot with a personal scope, it appears in the first tab position in a personal app by default. If you want to move it to another position, you must add a static tab object to your manifest with the reserved keyword, conversations. The conversation tab appears on web or desktop depending on where you add the conversation tab in the staticTabs array.

```
{
   "staticTabs":[
      {
         
      },
      {
         "entityId":"conversations",
         "scopes":[
            "personal"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-personal-tab?pivots=razor-csharp#reorder-static-personal-tabs